# Prove the following assertion: $a<0, b<0,$ then $ab>0$

Tags: inequality

I am reading *Inequalities* by Radmila Bulajich Manfrino. I am new to Inequalities, so I don't understand a lot.
The above mentioned problem is exercise $1.2(i)$ in the book. 
There are some properties mentioned before this exercise. They are:

> $1.1.1$ Every real number $x$ has one and only one of the following properties:
>         $(i) x = 0 \
>   (ii) x>0\
> (iii) -x>0$
>
> $1.1.2$ If $x>0, y>0 => x+y>0$
>
> $1.1.3$ If $x>0, y>0 => xy>0$

I tried to prove it in the following way:

$a<0 => -a>0$

$b<0 => -b>0$ (from property $1.1.1$)

$(-a)(-b)>0$ (from property $1.1.3$)

So, $ab>0$

I am confused if this is the correct proof. Can I write $(-a)(-b)=ab$, without referring to any properties?

Comment: I doubt many people have the book on hand, so an elaboration on both the property you wish to prove, and the properties you're allowed to use would be very useful for us.

Comment: By `a<0 = -a>0` do you mean $a<0 \iff -a > 0$?

Comment: @Brian Yes, that's what I mean. I'm sorry I don't know how to write it in this way.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer I have edited the question and added the properties

Comment: I think this is correct, provided you have already learned $-a<0\implies a>0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you claim you don't 'understand a lot', it is important to have the confidence in yourself that in what matters, you can be 'dead on balls accurate'.

Now what you are trying to prove you've known to be true from an early age, but now you want to be more sophisticated and abstract, using symbols that represent numbers together with some accepted properties.

I don't have your book, but I can wrap this up for you if we can agree on four more properties or 'things'. If the book doesn't explicitly state $\text{(1)}$ thru $\text{(3)}$ as valid properties, I am sure you can derive them within the book's framework.

$$\tag 1 (+1) \times u = u \text{ for any number } u$$
$$\tag 2 -u = (-1) \times u \text{ for any number } u$$
$$\tag 3  (-1) \times (-1) = 1$$
$$\tag 4 \text{Multiplication is both commutative and associative.}$$

You have shown that if both $a$ and $b$ are negative, that the product of $-a$ and $-b$ is positive. But $-a = (-1) \times a$ and $-b = (-1) \times b$, Now using $\text{(4)}$ it can be shown that
for every real numbers $s,t,u$ and $v$,

$$\tag 5 (su) \times (tv) = (st) \times (uv)$$

So,

$$\tag 6 0 \lt (-a)(-b) = ((-1) a) \times ((-1)b) = ((-1)(-1)) \times ab = (+1) \times ab = ab$$

Comment: Okay, this answer is very beautiful. Are the properties (1) to (4) field axioms?

Comment: @alu Those 4 properties are true for the integers.

Comment: @alu So the key to wrapping up your argument is showing that $-1 \times -1 = 1$.

Comment: @CopyPastelt I got it, -1 x -1 = 1 was what I was missing. So it is true for integers?

Comment: @alu yes, it is true for the integers, the rationals, the real numbers and the complex numbers.

Comment: @CopyPastelt I appreciate you encouraging me to be confident. I speak this way because I am learning this on my own, I don't have any degrees or help in real life, and I am new in this sort of proofs. Also I don't mean to sound whiny but I got condescended and people getting irritated on me when I did seek help. So seeking help has become difficult afterwards. Maybe some day I'll overcome all these and grow confidence.

Comment: @alu Hint: $-1 \times -1$ is the additive inverse of $-1$. What when added to $-1$ gives a result of $0$.

Comment: @CopyPastelt That's why I feel fortunate to have communities like this. They give me courage to pursue what my heart aches for.

Comment: @alu This site is invaluable as a companion resource for your studies. Good luck!

Comment: @CopyPastelt Thank you very much. I learned a lot from you today. For example, seeing -1 x -1 as the  the additive inverse of -1 is truly new and fascinating.

Answer (score 1):

I found the book the OP is using.

Working within the book's framework, the OP can also use the following argument:

Since $a \lt 0$ we can write $a + p = 0$ for some $p \gt 0$.
Since $b \lt 0\,$ we can write $b + q = 0$ for some $q \gt 0$.

Multiplying

$\tag 1 0 = 0 \times 0 = (a+p)(b+q) = ab +aq + pb + pq$

Since $aq = -pq$ and $pb = -pq$, by substituting in $\text{(1)}$,

$\tag 2 0 = ab - pq - pq + pq$

But then $ab = pq$. Using Property $1.1.3$ we see that the product of two negative numbers is positive.

Comment: It's beautiful how you can use completely different approach for the same proof.

Comment: Can you suggest me any books where I can learn the basics of proof by axioms?

Comment: @alu Googling around for online material, I found MIT OPEN COURSE WARE 6.042J / 2010: Mathematics for Computer Science. For Complete course notes, see https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-042j-mathematics-for-computer-science-fall-2010/readings/MIT6_042JF10_notes.pdf - skimmed it and it looked interesting.

Comment: @alu and definitely read $\text{2.7 Good Proofs in Practice}$.

Comment: Thank you. I'll check them out.